PHONE_REGISTRATION_ERROR / UNIMPLEMENTED GCM error on a device using javascript
We are using devices which has Linux OS, javascript enabled (using node.js). We are using google FCM to receive notifications. We are using a javascript library (added register() here) to get the fcm token by passing sender ID. It was all working fine. But from past few days we are getting PHONE_REGISTRATION_ERROR and UNIMPLEMENTED error / UNIMPLEMENTED error when we are trying to get the FCM token.
Below is the code snippet.

(async () => {                                                                                           
  try {                                                                                                                        
    const credentials = await register(senderID);
    const token = credentials.fcm.token;                                                                                                                                                               
    const persistentIds = [];
    await listen({ ...credentials, persistentIds }, onNotification);                                   
  } catch (e) {                                                                                                                                
    console.log("Error::" + e);                                                                                                                
  }                                                                                                                                            
})();

Below is the code for register function
const uuidv4 = require('uuid/v4');
const { register: registerGCM } = require('../gcm');
const registerFCM = require('../fcm');

module.exports = register;

async function register(senderId) {
  // Should be unique by app - One GCM registration/token by app/appId
  const appId = `wp:receiver.push.com#${uuidv4()}`;
  const subscription = await registerGCM(appId);
  const result = await registerFCM({
    token : subscription.token,
    senderId,
    appId,
  });
  // Need to be saved by the client
  return Object.assign({}, result, { gcm : subscription });
}

From past few days we are getting PHONE_REGISTRATION_ERROR and UNIMPLEMENTED error like below.
Register request has failed with Error=PHONE_REGISTRATION_ERROR
Retry... 1
Error::StatusCodeError: 501 - "{\n  \"error\": {\n    \"code\": 501,\n    \"message\": \"Operation is not implemented, or supported, or enabled.\",\n    \"status\": \"UNIMPLEMENTED\"\n  }\n}\n"

Or some times UNIMPLEMENTED error alone and unable to get the token. I tried to restart the devices multiple times but of no use.
I went through lot of questions online. All are showing issues with Android apps where the solution is like to clear cache, remove app and reinstall app. But I couldn't find a solution for this javascript based program. Can someone please let me know if there is anyway to solve this issue.

What is this "javascript library" you're referring to?  What are register and listen?  Is this JavaScript code effectively running in a browser, or some other environment like nodejs?  Please edit the question to show enough information that someone could use to reproduce the issue.

Updated the register function code.

What are const { register: registerGCM } = require('../gcm'); and const registerFCM = require('../fcm');?

I will point out also that FCM doesn't natively support nodejs for message receipt (only browsers, Android, and iOS).  You're doing something here that goes beyond what Google explicitly enables, and it's not clear.

Ok. To be clear we are using this library https://github.com/MatthieuLemoine/push-receiver/blob/aa603d65b0476e0d47371277f9122835fabdd839/src/gcm/index.js#L11. That was the only library we included for notification support. I am not sure why it suddenly stops working w/o any changes.

The javascript library push-receiver is using legacy APIs of firebase. FB stopped supporting these APIs which is the reason for the failure. We changed our code to use push-receiver-v2 library which fixed the issue.
